# How do I escape ${} in my Tridion Component Template that is consumed by multiple templates?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am running into a situation where I have a fied with the value `${test}`, in my component template that renders this the value comes out ok the problem comes in when another template  calls this component and templates using `@@RenderComponentPresentation(Component.ID, MyFirstTemplate)@@` at this point the `${test}` is evaluated and because there is no such item on the component or in the package it evaluates to nothing.

- I have Component Template One that reads the value of a Component field (which contains: `${test}`)

  - This template renders fine, I get back "${test}"
- Now I have Component Template Two that calls `@@RenderComponentPresentation(Component.ID, ComponentTemplateOne.ID)@@`

  - This is where the `${test}` now gets evaluated instead of retained so it goes from `${test}` to "" because it doesn't find a variable or component field name with that name.
- Component Template Two then gets called by Component Template Three in the same way `@@RenderComponentPresentation(Component2.ID, ComponentTemplateTwo.ID)@@`

  - Since the `${test}` has already been evaluated and lost in Component Template Two I no longer end up with `${test}` I am still left with "".

I have tried:

- `@@RenderComponentField('myField', 0, False, False)@@`
- `@@RenderComponentField('myField', 0, True, False)@@`
- `@@RenderComponentField('myField', 0, False, True)@@`

no luck.

The following was my work around and it seems to work:

- Placing the "\" in front of both the open and close curly brace `$\{test\}`
- I need to make sure I remove the "\" after the last Template (Page or Component) executes.
- I have in place now a C# TBB that takes the "${test}" and does the following to it:

  - Converts the `${test}` to  `$\{test\}` in the initial template and a C# TBB on the Page Template that then returns it to the initial value of `${test}`.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening or a way to avoid doing what i am doing to make this work?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this [link](http://feedreader.com/feed/Coded_Weapon/14508699) , you should be able to this with this link

```
@@"$" + "{" + "test" + "}"@@
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion it works for the first template but the second template that calls the first template evaluates it and doesn't find an item in the package or in the component by that name and reutrns nothing. So instead of retaining ${endpoint} i get "".